# Sql Server, Insert and/or Select binary data issue

Tags: sql-server, base64, binary-data, varbinarymax

I'm having a problem either inserting or selecting data from a varbinary(max) column in my database (it is a localDB) and I can't seem to figure out why.

I'm adding the binary data from a C# application the following way.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("<connection string...>");            
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_test_varbinary", con);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@content", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = Convert.FromBase64String("<base64 string>");

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

The *sp_test_varbinary* stored procedure takes just the one parameter *@content* and inserts it into a varbinary(max) column - so far all seems to work as expected. I can't tell what is in the varbinary(max) column, since it just says *binary data*, but something is there at least.

Then when I try to select the row I just inserted and attempt to get back the base64 string i originally had, something goes wrong or the data in the field is wrong.

I'm doing the following (file_id is the ID of the row I added).

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [content] FROM [BaseFiles] WHERE ([file_id] = '" + file_id + "');", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);

string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows["content"]);
```

At this point however, the base64 variable only contains the value:

> 7w==

Any idea what I'm missing to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your result you more than likely did not specify the length of the `VARBINARY` in either your stored procedure, table or code within the stored procedure.

Make sure that when you declare a `VARBINARY` variable that you included the `MAX` definition in your declaration. Example your stored procedure should be declared as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test_varbinary]
    @content AS VARBINARY(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- YOUR INSERT STATEMENT HERE

END
```

And not declared as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test_varbinary]
    @content AS VARBINARY
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- YOUR INSERT STATEMENT HERE

END
```

Similar make sure that if you use a local `VARBINARY` variables within your stored procedure that their lengths is also defined. Final make sure that the length of the `VARBINARY` is defined on the `[content]` column within your table.